# Executing PHP and BASH's shell script has different outcome

Tags: php, xml, bash, shell, xslt

I have a question regarding different outcome between PHP's `shell_exec` and Ubuntu's `sh`.

## Background

I am trying to build a web-based SDLXLIFF-XML bidirectional converter. I'm using XSLT to actually control the data, but the program in based on local installation of Java JRE and DITA-OT.

To help the users from having to install Java and DITA-OT, I'm developing an online version, so users can just upload and download source files.

### Server

- Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS
- PHP 7.0.4
- Apache 2.4
- Korean Locale (`kr-KO.UTF-8`)

## Problem

SDLXLIFF2XML words fine. Process is as follows:

1. Upload SDLXLIFF file and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. PHP executes `shell_exec('sh 01.sh');`.
3. `01.sh` runs XSLT, and then zip the XML files.
4. PHP opens the download dialog for the zip file, and then `@unlink`s it.

The problem is with XML2SDLXLIFF. Process is almost the same:

1. Upload the ZIP file and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
2. PHP executes `shell_exec('sh 02.sh');`.
3. `02.sh` extracts the ZIP file, and then runs XSLT.
4. PHP opens the download dialog for SDLXLIFF file, and then `@unlink`s it.

The actual XSLT conversion is fine, but the file naming isn't. English shows fine, but Korean characters are all shown as ?. For example (Don't mind the Korean character below. It just means 'Korean').,

- Expected result: Testing_transformation_한글.sdlxliff
- Actual result: Testing_transformation_??.sdlxliff

PHP, XSLT, and SH sources for both process are almost identical, except for the reversing process.

One difference is that SDLXLIFF2XML's file naming is based on the uploaded filename, and XML2SDLXLIFF's is based on a string INSIDE the XML file.

SDLXLIFF2XML shows multibyte characters just fine, but it's not working the other way around.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the encoding of the XML file? Is it UTF-8?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Yes, it's UTF-8. It's been declared within the file as well.